# Strange Behavior with Private Contexts in 10.0.1

Tags: contexts, version-10

I have noticed the following weird behavior when creating Private `Context` in **V 10.0.1**, a behavior not present in **V 10.0.0**.

```
$Context
```

> ```
> "Global`"
> ```

```
BeginPackage["testing`"]
```

> ```
> "testing`"
> ```

```
$Context
```

> ```
> "testing`"
> ```

Now we create a `Private` sub-context

```
Begin["`Private`"]
```

> ```
> testing`Private`
> ```

Everything looks good so far until this:

```
$Context
```

> ```
> "testing`Private`Private`"
> ```

So instead of being in the `` testing`Private `` sub-context, *Mathematica* has entered a sub-sub-context.

I've verified this on **Windows** and **Linux**. Can anyone verify this behavior in **V10.0.1**?

Comment: It seems that I cannot reproduce this behavior in 10.0.1 under Windows 7.  Do you have any kind of `$PreRead` etc. that would cause ``Begin["`Private`"]`` to be evaluated twice?

Comment: Neither can I, Mac OS X. Chances are that you executed ``Begin["`Private`"]`` twice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I just tested again, I have nothing in `$PreRead` or any System symbols. And I did not execute ``Begin["`Private`"]`` twice.

Comment: `$PreRead` is not the only way something might be evaluated twice.  Try adding `-noinit` to your launch arguments in Kernel Properties, and test the evaluation in a blank Notebook.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. How do I get to this Kernel Properties you speak of? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. If somehow, I executed ``Begin["`Private`"]`` twice, why does the output show ``testing`Private`` and not ``testing`Private`Private``?

Comment: @RunnyKine I meant, you could accidentally execute the cell with ``Begin["`Private`"]`` once again, and not pay attention to the second output. That was just a guess.

Comment: I am referring to menu **Evaluation** > **Kernel Configuration Options...**.  Then choose **Add** and select **Advanced Options** then edit the launch command accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks, I just tried that but still getting the same result. This is really weird, I wonder if it has to do with the fact I'm on **Windows 10 TP**. I'll have to try it on **Windows 8.1** to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I agree it's strange, but *Mathematica* is a complex system and "strange behavior" is often hard to reproduce.  (On the other hand a few times I have assumed that what I was experience was "too weird" to be a problem everyone had only to later see a question about it and confirmation that it was a common issue.)  By the way I pay so little attention to computer/tech news these days that I had never heard of *Windows 10* before.  My first thought was "what happened to Windows 9?" and sure enough that is one of the first results on a search for *Windows 10*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Lol about **Windows 10**. The preview was just announced this week, but it's so much better than 8, I decided to try it right away. About this weird behavior, what actually led me to ask this question was because I have a Linux trial version (10.0.1) installed on Ubuntu (on a virtual machine), and I see the exact behavior there too.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior (Win 7 / Mathematica 10.0.2.0)